# I'm getting this error when I import Chakra UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, chakra-ui

I'm getting this error when I imported Chakra UI.

```
   
   if (variantColorIsDefined) {
      var variantColorExists = variantColor in theme.colors; // If variant color exists in theme object
       ^  114 | 
    if (!variantColorExists) {
      console.warn("You passed an invalid variantColor to the " + label + " Component. Variant color values must be a color key in the theme object that has '100' - '900' color values. Check http://chakra-ui.com/theme#colors to see possible values");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bit hard to understand from the docs, a variant color is actually a set of colors.

in your theme you need to define a color and a corresponding :hover value like e.g. so:

```
yellow: {
  500: "#FFFF80",  //this is the default color
  600: "#FFFF00"   //this is the color on hover
},
```

then you reference it in your component like so:

```
<IconButton size="sm" icon="unicorn" isRound variantColor="yellow" />
```